# Finding an Elliptic Curve with 103 points

Tags: modular-arithmetic, self-learning, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Find an elliptic curve over **F**101 with 103 points.

I know all of the equations when needing to find alpha, and beta and all that when I am given two points P and Q on an already given Elliptic Curve, however dont know how to go about finding a specific Elliptic Curve with a certain amount of points.

Using a theorem:
I know that if P is a prime (101 is prime) and N (103) is an integer satisfying

|N-(p+1)|≤ 2√p

This holds so I know there exists an elliptic Curve E mod p with exactly N points. I just dont know how to find this specific curve E

Thanks

Comment: But the theorem I listed above, shows and proves that such a curve exists

Comment: Or if I am wrong, how are you certain that no curve exists?

Comment: I was wrong, there are many such curves. Try $y^2 = x^3 -3x+2 \mod 101$. Note however that the theorem by Hasse gives a bound on the number of points on the curve, but it does not give existence.

Comment: There is a method to construct curves with a specified number of points called the CM-method, CM as in complex multiplication. See e.g. page 3 of this http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6983v1.pdf the steps involved are not so complicated